# IE Ul LI Padding?

Tags: css

[Check this link!](http://mibsoftware.us/clients/dogwatch/dogwatch.html)

I am having the hardest time trying to figure out why my last li item is being pushed to the bottom in IE. I have the width, height set for the container. The li has padding/margin to 0. Li is float left. Still being pushed down. Seeking a Guru to help a n00b here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting `margin:0` to the `ul` rule ..

The automatic margin the IE assigns, decreases the width available to contain the floated elements, and so they wrap ...

Comment: I agree, using reset-style-sheets saves from many headaches, but on the other hand, i also find important to know how/why something works (or not). ( *even if it is in IE :)* )

Answer (score 1):

Your example page is completely invalid.  Try adding a doctype, html, head and body tags and try again.

(Having said that, it looks fine in IE.)

Answer (score -1):

Float the LIs, don't make them inline.

```
#widget_container ul {
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    }
#widget_container ul li {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    float:left;     
    }
```

Comment: I've added your code yet it's still pushing items to the bottom?

Comment: ah nm, Gaby's fix fixed it :)

Comment: -1: why would he switch a correct approach to one that doesn't even change anything and adds `clear: left;` needs?

Comment: I've always used a CSS reset, which is why the fix was non-obvious to me.